# why the probability of infinite oscillation is zero in the gambler's ruin problem.

Tags: probability

I came to know about the Gambler's ruin problem recently. $p$ and $q$ are the probability of getting a head and a tail respectively in one flip of the coin. A is a player starting the game with $i$ and B is another player starting with $N-i$. Then the probability that A wins the game is $P(A)$= $\frac{(1-(q/p)^i)}{(1-(q/p)^N}$.
$P(B)=\frac{1-(q/p)^{N-i}}{(1-(q/p)^N}$.
if $p=q$ then the probability is $P(A)$= $\frac{i}{N}$ and $P(B)$=$\frac{N-i}{N}$
Then $1-P(A)-P(B)$ is the probability of oscillation.
if coin is unbiased, then the probability of oscillation is $0$.
but what if the coin is biased?
and again if the coin is fair then there can be one event {$H,T,H,T,H......$},here $A$ gets one point from $B$ and then right after that $B$ gets one point from $A$
This way the oscillation can go forever intuitively. I'm not getting this part. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean with oscillation a single $H,T$ sequence or an infinite string $H,T,H,T,H,T,\cdots$. The latter (as any infinite string , except $H,H,H,\cdots$ if $H$ has probability $1$ and the analogue case for $T,T,T,\cdots$) has probability $0$ no matter what the probability for $H$ is.

Comment: @Peter Sorry, I could not completely get your 1st point (oscillation a single H,T seqn) but I was talking about the case where A is just starting with i pts and the results of the flip start showing such a sequence {H,T,H,T...}

Comment: @Peter yes now I understood that the prob of infinite oscillation {H,T,H,T,H..} is 0. Thank you. but can we show mathematically using the formula 1-P(A)-P(B) for the biased coin that the probability is 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can show the same for the biased case as well.

The P(B) you have mentioned for the biased case is slightly incorrect.

It would rather be:

$P(B) = {1-\left({p\over q}\right)^{N-i} \over 1-\left({p\over q}\right)^N}$

To get the intuition of why that is the case, think of the formula as this:

- For a player with i dollars, winning probability p and losing probability q, the probability of winning the complete game is what we computed as P(A)
- For Player B, dollars change to N-i, also, winning and losing probabilities switch places.

With that in place, you can easily show the sum of P(A) and P(B) to equate to zero.

Comment: Now I got the point at last. The switch of the probabilities was the crucial point. Thank you very much.